# How to use UpperCase filter in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Is there a way I can do this with Angular Filter? For some reasons I'm not allowed to do it by Javascript ways, and creating additional files is not allowed as well

BTW, the purpose of the codes is to compare the users inputs whatever it is uppercase or lowercase, not just display the varName

```
<span data-ng-show="varName.toUpperCase() == 'YOURNAME'">
    Aswsome name !</span>

<span data-ng-hide="varName.toUpperCase() == 'YOURNAME'">
    {{varName}} is not my name.</span>
```

I have tried something like this but failed

```
<span data-ng-show="varName|uppercase == 'YOURNAME'">
    Aswsome name !</span>
```

Comment: try this <span> {{ varName| uppercase }}</span>

Comment: What you are doing is correct and works (I just double checked)

Comment: Yes it is correct but I'm learnning AngularJS, my tutor told me we only allow use angular filter to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

you have to use like this ....

```
   {{ uppercase_expression | uppercase}}
```

Example :

```
   <div ng-app>

    <p>
        <label>Enter your name (in lower case)</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourname" />
    </p>

    <p> {{ yourname | uppercase }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: actually the purpose of my codes is to compare the user input whatever it is uppercase or lowercase

Answer (score 1):

You can convert strings to uppercase with this [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase)

In HTML Template Binding:

```
{{ varName | uppercase}}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var editer = angular.module('editer', []);
function myCtrl($scope) {
$scope.varName = "yourname";
  
  $scope.toUpperCase = function(){
    return $scope.varName.toUpperCase();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
   
   <span data-ng-show="toUpperCase() == 'YOURNAME'">
    Aswsome name !</span>

<span data-ng-hide="toUpperCase() == 'YOURNAME'">
    {{varName}} is not my name.</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put parentheses around the first 2 operands

```
<span ng-show="(varName | uppercase) == 'YOURNAME'">
    Aswsome name !</span>
</div>
```